# How to Add XML File in Array collection in Flex?

Tags: xml, apache-flex

i have created one array collection in flex.and i have my one XML file.
Now i want to call that XML file into arraycollection,so please give me ideas about the same.
How can i achieve this???

Thanks in Advance---

Answer (score 0):

First extract [`XMLList`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XMLList.html) with desired nodes from your XML. Then use [`ArrayUtil.toArray()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/utils/ArrayUtil.html#toArray%28%29) the following way:

```
var myCollection:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection(ArrayUtil.toArray(myXMLList));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!-- Application -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600" creationComplete="creationCompleteHandler(event)">

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

        [Bindable]
        private var arrColl:ArrayCollection;

        protected function creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            arrColl = new ArrayCollection(books.book);  
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Model id="books" source="books.xml"/>
</fx:Declarations>
```

```
<!-- books.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<books>
    <book>
        <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
        <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
        <genre>Computer</genre>
        <price>44.95</price>
    </book>
    <book>
        <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
        <title>Midnight Rain</title>
        <genre>Fantasy</genre>
        <price>5.95</price>
    </book>
<books>
```